# Vue v-for showing wierd behaviour upon updating the array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My project currently has a list of Comments stored in an array called `feedbackList`.
Let's say that each comment contains a Author and Feedback string.

So, my feedbackList would be something like;

```
feedbackList: [
  {name: 'John', comment: 'a nice comment'},
  {name: 'Steve', comment: 'first comment'}
]
```

These are then displayed using some code such as;

```
<div class="comment-wrapper" v-for="(comment, index) in feedbackList" :key="index">
  <CommentCard
    v-bind:author="comment.author"
    v-bind:comment="comment.comment"
    v-on:DeleteComment="DeleteComment($event)"
  />
</div>
```

Then, I use a function to submit a new comment, containing this;

```
const newcomment = {
  author: this.author
  comment: this.feedback,
  timePosted: moment().format()
}
this.feedbackList.unshift(newcomment)
```

However, the issue is as I push the new comment to the beggining of the array, my comments shuffle down in an odd way.

I will now appear as the person below me (author), but with my own comment.
The post below that will take on the one before that, with the previous author but their own comment, and so on and so on.

If I use `.push(newcomment)` it adds the new comment to the bottom as intended. However, then comes the issue of deleting a comment, making the previous one now take over the recently delete author, but their own comment.

I know this is a little confusing, but essentially upon updating my array, it seems the v-for is not updating the attached data correctly and giving the correct comment but previous author.

Comment: i readed that the index itself isnt the best approach to define your `:key=""`. i would create an own unique key and add it to your object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your index is binded as a `key`. Try adding an `id` variable (unique for every comment, it can be an incrementing number or a random string) and use that as your `key` in `v-for`.

Example:

```js
feedbackList: [
  {id: 'nlgvn5d6', name: 'John', comment: 'a nice comment'},
  {id: '85m18efd', name: 'Steve', comment: 'first comment'}
]
```

Remeber that when adding a new item to the list it also needs to have its own unique id.

Then you can use it like this:

```html
v-for="comment in feedbackList" :key="comment.id"
```

Comment: "it can be an incrementing number or a **random string**" > A random string as ID, so what if we're (accidentally) generate the same 'random' string? Just use an _auto increment_ ID....

Comment: Oh right yes, that makes complete sense!
So, instead of using index for key, I would instead use the unique ID each comment has? And, this would be passed through in the v-for like v-for="(comment, id) in feedbackList" :key="id" ?

Comment: @KJParker yes, exactly.

Comment: @0stone0 I would say it depends on the type and scale of data. There are ways to generate string ids in a way that it's practically impossible to generate a duplicate. (such as UUID)

Comment: @KJParker I just realized you have an error in your comment there. You are still assigning your index to a key attribute (only in this case the variable is called id instead of index). I've updated my answer on how you can use the id as a key.